# What does this mean? I am trying to upgrade my version 12.04 Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  mingw-w64 sbsigntool libnet-ssleay-perl gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 linux-image-3.5.0-22-generic realpath efibootmgr libunistring0 diffstat
  libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libdebconfclient0 binutils-mingw-w64-i686 libxml-parser-perl liburi-perl libhtml-parser-perl kpartx-boot libopts25
  gir1.2-json-1.0 libhttp-daemon-perl linux-headers-3.5.0-22-generic autogen libfont-afm-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libfile-listing-perl
  libhtml-form-perl gcc-mingw-w64 user-setup gcc-mingw-w64-i686 kpartx libhtml-tree-perl libencode-locale-perl rdate libhttp-date-perl
  libmailtools-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-message-perl binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 libdebian-installer4
  libopts25-dev libnet-http-perl btrfs-tools apt-clone localechooser-data linux-headers-3.5.0-22 gcc-mingw-w64-base libhtml-format-perl
  libgettextpo0 libsocket6-perl gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 libhtml-tagset-perl archdetect-deb dmraid python-pyicu libkms1 libwww-perl mingw-w64-dev
  libio-socket-ssl-perl libwww-robotrules-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl gir1.2-xkl-1.0 libio-socket-inet6-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Comment: 12.04 hit end-of-life on April 28, 2017. Switching to a supported release involves either doing a fresh install, or temporarily using the old-releases repositories. See [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/301745)

Comment: How to do a fresh install?

Comment: My guess (*on your error*) would be you haven't changed `archive.ubuntu.com` to the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` , or if you have made that change, you haven't run `sudo apt-get update` to update your software (repo) lists to reflect the change to make 14.04 LTS visible.

Comment: @Maria Fresh install means to make a backup, then totally reinstall the OS.

Comment: How to make backup? I need a hard disk? Does this mean everything will be erased?

Comment: @Maria If you were to do a fresh install, yes. But as I said, you could upgrade instead. Btw, you should make a backup regardless. Backups are important.

Answer (score 0):

**The Output of your message meaning:**
You have unused packages that had at one time been installed to support some other application(s) that are no longer installed.  The packages can be removed.  It's also showing you the command to remove the leftover packages: `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

**You can upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.**  I was already sure, but just before posting, I tested to verify that it would work.  I installed 12.04 LTS on a VM and upgraded it without any problems.

You'll have to run a combination of these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After the **upgrade** commands, run this:

```
$ ls /var/run/*reboot*
```

If one of these lines included in the output, reboot the computer to make changes become in effect:

```
/var/run/reboot-required
/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
```

Between the commands, look at the screen as you already have and perform the steps provided by the screen's output to fix problems.  In the case of your current problem on your screen, it's telling you to perform this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The error `No new release found` can be resolved with the third command in the list above.  The `dist-upgrade` is different from the `upgrade` option, whereas the `dist-upgrade` will remove outdated libraries and remove applications that were installed with the old libraries.

If they are applications that you need, you can address those issues and reinstall the `ppa's` or other dependents later, or get updated versions of those programs that don't carry over.

Comment: dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ $ sudo apt-get update
$: command not found
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
$: command not found
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$: command not found
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ $ sudo apt-get autoremove
$: command not found
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ 

I tried running those but this is what it said.

Comment: Don't put the `$` in front of the command.  The `$` is already on your terminal.  It's there to show you that it's a command that you are executing.

Comment: Removing libnet-http-perl ...
Removing libnet-ssleay-perl ...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-61-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ ^C
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ 
Now what does this mean? What shall I do next?

Comment: Looking at what you have pasted to the chat, it appears that you hit the `Ctrl` + `C` and interupted the process.  That's kind of dangerous.  You have to let the computer complete the process and only hit a key when the system ask you a question, or when you have the `$` prompt again, whereas you can execute other commands.  Try hitting the `up-arrow` on the keyboard, then press `ENTER` to run the previous command again.  The sysem is showing you what it's doing.  Some of the processes may take a long time.   Only be concerned when you see the word `error` included in the text.

Comment: i am sorry i have erased the terminal, do have to repeat all again? How do I know if the procedure has stopped? How long does it really take to upgrade? dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ 
when this always shows

Comment: You will see the `$` prompt, with no text after it.  The `$` prompt is indicating that the computer is waiting (or promoting) you for input.  Looking at what you pasted to the comments, your prompt looks like this: `dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$`.  If you don't see that, the computer is busy.  The `sudo do-release-upgrade` can take an hour to compete the process.  The text on the screen often tells the user a process may take a long time.

Comment: You haven't removed the commands that you have typed in.  Just hit the `up-arrow` on your keyboard.  You can see the last command that you typed in.

Comment: Once you see the last command you typed in, press `ENTER` to execute it again.

Comment: My version 12.04 is still the same, I cannot upgrade it. I dont know why. I already did all those commands

Comment: You can upgrade.  It's a matter of responding to the output that you see on your screen.   Will you show the output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`?

Comment: dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"  I have followed those commands, first I copy [sudo apt-get update] to terminal and run it, and then next [sudo apt-get upgrade],then so on ... Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: No.  You appear to be doing it ok.  Will you provide the output of: `ls /var/run/*reboot*`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78254/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-what-does-this-mean-i-am-trying-to-upgrade).

Comment: dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ file:///home/dianne/Downloads/XiaoYing_Video_1489823322304.mp4 
bash: file:///home/dianne/Downloads/XiaoYing_Video_1489823322304.mp4: No such file or directory
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ ls /var/run/*reboot*
/var/run/crond.reboot
dianne@dianne-Inspiron-3437:~$ That is what it shows

Comment: @MariaDianne You put the information in the wrong place.  Please put the information [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78254/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-what-does-this-mean-i-am-trying-to-upgrade), then look for an update in the same place.  The information will be formatted and substantially easier to read.